# Jupyter Book - Changing LateX preamble for PDFLatex based compilation

Tags: python, latex, jupyter, jupyterbook

- I am using TexLive 2022 on Mac OSX.
- I am using Jupyter Book to write a textbook with Python snippets, with a lot of mathematics in it.
- I have been able to create Python notebooks with extension `.ipynb` for the various chapters therein.
- I have changed the table of contents in the `_config.yml` file

With this context, I wish to ask how to change the base fonts for math and text type settings. For example I would wish to use the `pxfonts` package. Essentially, I wish to know how to control the preamble of latex.

See [this link](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/advanced/pdf.html) for more information on Jupyter Book and PDF.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your linked page, I found the following:

> Configuration via Sphinx LaTeX settings can be passed through using the config section of sphinx in the _config.yml file for your project.

Here is more on _config.yml: https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/customize/config.html

Here is more on Sphinx: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html?highlight=latex%20package

Have you added the following to your _config.yml?

```
sphinx:
  config:
    latex_elements:
      preamble: '\usepackage{pxfonts}'
```

If that does not work, you could build to latex with `jb build --builder latex /path/to/notebooks`, then manually edit the .tex file.